# pom management failed by dependencyManagement

Tags: java, spring, maven

I use `<dependencyManagement>` to manage my lib:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.manulife.hk</groupId>
                <artifactId>hk-verctl-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I use the `hk-verctl-dependencies` manage my lib(The `<parent>` tag is already in use, and I can only use the `hk-verctl-dependencies` project to manage the version of the third-party libs for each service )

I have manage `tomcat-embed-core` in `hk-verctl-dependencies`:

```
     <properties>
        <!-- Compiler & Parent Properties -->
        <java.version>17</java.version>

        <version.swagger>2.10.0</version.swagger>
        <version.bcprov-jdk15on>1.69</version.bcprov-jdk15on>
        <version.reactor-netty>1.0.24</version.reactor-netty>
        <version.jose4j>0.9.3</version.jose4j>
        <version.protobuf-java>3.19.6</version.protobuf-java>
        <version.okio>3.4.0</version.okio>
        <version.woodstox-core>5.4.0</version.woodstox-core>
        <version.bcprov-jdk18on>1.74</version.bcprov-jdk18on>
        <version.guava>32.0.0-jre</version.guava>
        <version.fastjson>1.2.83</version.fastjson>
        <version.tomcat-embed-core>10.1.13</version.tomcat-embed-core>
        <version.spring-security-oauth2>2.5.2.RELEASE</version.spring-security-oauth2>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
                <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
                <version>${version.fastjson}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
                <version>${version.tomcat-embed-core}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${version.guava}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
                <version>${version.bcprov-jdk18on}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bitbucket.b_c</groupId>
                <artifactId>jose4j</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jose4j}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                <version>${version.protobuf-java}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
                <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
                <version>${version.okio}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
                <version>${version.woodstox-core}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                <version>${version.bcprov-jdk15on}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
                <version>${version.reactor-netty}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${version.swagger}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${version.swagger}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                <version>${version.spring-security-oauth2}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

And I import `tomcat-embed-core` in my business service:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.manulife.hk</groupId>
                <artifactId>hk-verctl-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <!-- Project dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Begin Fast Json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- End Fast Json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk18on</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

All other dependencies successfully apply the version of `hk-verctl-dependencies`, only tomcat-embed-core doesn't, why is that?

Comment: What is the parent you are using as if that also managed the same dependency that will take precedence (afaik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say "the `<parent>` tag is already in use".  I guess that this parent is `spring-boot-starter-parent`.  The Tomcat dependency is the only one that is present in `spring-boot-starter-parent` too and the one inherited from the parent takes precedence.

The correct way to override a dependency inherited from `spring-boot-starter-parent` is to create in your POM a property with the **same name** used by Spring and the new version as value, for example:

```
<tomcat.version>10.1.13</tomcat.version>
```

This line, even  without a `<dependencyManagement>` section, will manage the version of `tomcat-embed-core`.  You can find the name of any `*.version` property that you want to override in `spring-boot-dependencies` that is parent of  `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

As an alternative you could set `spring-boot-starter-parent` as the parent of `hk-verctl-dependencies` and `hk-verctl-dependencies` as the parent of your project.  In this way your project can have two parents, that is a parent and a grandparent.

Comment: Thanks ,I solved this problem by use <tomcat.version>10.1.13</tomcat.version>.